# Meaning of Hilbert space adjointable

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, unbounded-operators

If $T$ is a densely defined operator on a Hilbert space $\mathbf{H}$, then one can mimic the Riesz representation theorem to define an adjoint operator for $T$ whose domain is given by all those elements  $x \in \mathbf{H}$ such that the map
$$
\text{Dom}(T) \to \mathbb{C}, ~~~~ y \mapsto \langle x, T(y)\rangle
$$
is bounded (where the inner product is linear in the first variable). The domain can of course be $0$, however, the adjoint always exists.

In the literature on bounded operators on Hilbert spaces (and Hilbert modules) however, one often speaks of an **adjointable** operator. Am I correct in guessing that the this precisely means that the adjoint of the operator is defined everywhere. Since otherwise the adjective would be trivial.